# How to connect a Linux machine to a repeater WiFi?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to create a repeater from my Zyxel P-870HN-53b router and connect to its WiFi. I have followed the following steps:

1. I have connected router 1 with router 2 with a LAN cable placing its ends to Ethernet sockets
2. I have reset the second router (Zyxel P-870HN-53b) by pressing its reset button and wait after the router blinked red
3. Then I connected this router via a LAN cable with my PC, i.e one side went to the router's Ethernet socked, the other to the socked on my PC
4. I have switched off the wifi on my Laptop via *wifi:disable wifi connections*
5. I have opened the MATE terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
6. I typed in `ip r` and copied the IP address into my browser URL line (it was 10.0.0.138)
7. The pop-up windows appeared, so I set a username and a password, I was allowed to the router settings
8. I disabled the DHCP server and saved
9. I have changed IP Address to 10.0.0.250 and saved
10. I have enabled the WiFi, set it to a different name, then on router 1, set a password and saved
11. I have removed a LAN cable from my laptop and clicked on the new Wi-Fi name to connect it

While I can connect to the WiFi from my cell phone (which has MIUI) or from a laptop with Windows, I am not able to connect and use the WiFi with my Ubuntu. How should I set up both sites to be able to connect to this WiFi?

Comment: Thank you for the edit (and @Giacomo1968 for the clean-up)- However, there's still one crucial detail missing: What exactly happens when you try to connect in Ubuntu?

Comment: Elaborating on the question, I repeated the process of adding the wifi and finally my laptop was connected (a few times, nothing happened and I was not connected). Now I am not able to connect from my other PC with Windows. So it looks like, there is a problem on the side of a router and that I may need a different question. @ChanganAuto you were probably right that the process is correct and should work for all systems. Should I delete this question then?